# Animation while clicking

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have added MouseLeftButtonUp event to a canvas to capture click(or touch) event. Right now, when the canvas is clicked there is no indication to the user that he has clicked on it(means there is no pressed effect). How do I create such an effect when the canvas is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

For a canvas this will be tricky. Could you not use a button instead? You could put the contents of the canvas in the buttons content. You can then use the Visual States of the button to indicated when it is being pressed.

Alternatively you could use the Manipulation events on the control and change how it looks accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the toolkit installed, you can set enable TiltEffect by setting

```
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

and then you will need to wrap your Canvas with a Control, say, a Button.

I have actually used a ListBoxItem to receive the tilt effect. :)

```
        <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
            <Canvas Margin="{StaticResource PhoneVerticalMargin}" Background="Transparent">
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/xxxView.xaml" />
                    </Custom:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/5/C0560669-D330-463D-9021-C31770290F3A/ControlTiltEffect.zip) example project from download.microsoft.com. It contains TiltEffect.cs which you can add to your own project e.g. in a .xaml file (see the last line):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="NavigationTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavigationTest" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
```